# Azure : what protocol is used for communication with cache

Tags: caching, azure

In an azure cloud service having a cache, how do the various instances of roles interact with the cache? what protocol is used for the communication?

Comment: Based on the errors we see with caching, I would say net.tcp.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the new Shared Cache service, it's a proprietary protocol over TCP.